# Unity3D Save Mobile GUI Button

Tags: android, user-interface, mobile, unity-game-engine, save

I have the code for desktop by pressing p but I cannot get a mobile gui button instead. I've been using Corona SDK and am new to Unity3D. Please help me make the "press p" into a GUI button that says "Save." Thanks in advance!!!

```
import System.Collections.Generic;

var paused : boolean = false; 
var pausedGUI : GUITexture;  
var gameName : String = "Your Game";

var myList = new List.<Transform>();

function Start()
{
    if(pausedGUI)
        pausedGUI.enabled = false;
}

function Update () 
{ 
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.P))
    { 
       paused = !paused;

        if(paused == true){
            Time.timeScale = 0.0;
            if(pausedGUI) pausedGUI.enabled = true;
        } else {
            Time.timeScale = 1.0;
            if(pausedGUI) pausedGUI.enabled = false;
        }
   }
}

function OnGUI() {
    if(!paused)
    {
       GUILayout.BeginArea(Rect(200,10,400,20));
       GUILayout.BeginVertical();
       GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
       GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
       GUILayout.Label("Press P to Pause");
       GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
       GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
       GUILayout.EndVertical();
       GUILayout.EndArea();
       return;
    }

    var box : GUIStyle = "box";   
    GUILayout.BeginArea(Rect( Screen.width/2 - 200,Screen.height/2 - 300, 400, 600), box);

    GUILayout.BeginVertical(); 
    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
    if(GUILayout.Button("Save Game"))
    {
       LevelSerializer.SaveGame(gameName);
    }
    GUILayout.Space(60);
    for(var sg in LevelSerializer.SavedGames[LevelSerializer.PlayerName]) { 
       if(GUILayout.Button(sg.Caption)) { 
         LevelSerializer.LoadNow(sg.Data);
         Time.timeScale = 1;
         } 
    } 
    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
    GUILayout.EndVertical();
    GUILayout.EndArea();


}
```

Check Out My Games Here: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Kyle+Figula)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is place a button at the start of the OnGUI call which will toggle the paused state

```
function OnGUI(){
  if(!paused){
    if(GUILayout.Button("Pause Game"))
    {
      paused = true;
    }
  }else{
    if(GUILayout.Button("Resume Game"))
    {
      paused = false;
    }
  }

...
```

Sorry if syntax is a bit off i usually do this is C# :)

You will need to do the formatting to place the button in the right place, but that depends on your game layout

Hope this helps